# Work and walking with a bowling ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

I want to check myself on some basic things: Assume I am holding a heavy bowling ball straight out in front of me. And assume that when I walk I am able to carry the ball in such a way that it strictly moves in a straight line parallel to the ground (so at a fixed height). My question is: are the following three statements true?

1. If I walk at the constant velocity $\vec{v}=1\hat{i}$ and there is no drag then no work is being done on the bowling ball
2. If I walk at the constant velocity $\vec{v}=1\hat{i}$ and there **is** drag then both I and the air are doing work on the ball: $W_{air on ball}=-W_{meonball}$
3. If I accelerate while I walk such that my velocity is $\vec{v}=a_{walk}t\hat{i}$ and there is no drag then, for a walk of length $\Delta x$, $W_{meonball}=m_{ball}a_{walk}\Delta x$

Comment: I removed a couple of comments; please keep in mind that comments are to be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on their parent post, not for answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

$W = F\Delta d$

where $\Delta d$ is in the direction of the force.

- Question 1: $\Delta d$ is zero, so no work. Your assertion is true.
- Question 2: $F$ is the drag, $\Delta d$ is the distance walked. Your assertion is true.
- Question 3: Since $F = ma$. Your assertion is true.